# c# windows store app granting capabilities to used dll-s

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I'd like to use TagLib in my Windows Store project. 
The TagLib is imported as reference, with its dll ( taglib-sharp.dll ) 
I can access any file in my music folder since it is checked in the capabilities. However, when I call

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(soundFilePath, TagLib.ReadStyle.None);
```

it throws the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024891
Message=Access to the path 'C:\Users\Gabor\Music\_FIFA 2010 soundtracks\01. Meine Stadt - Auletta.mp3' is denied.
Source=taglib-sharp
StackTrace:
   at TagLib.File.Create(IFileAbstraction abstraction, String mimetype, ReadStyle propertiesStyle)
   at TagLib.File.Create(String path, String mimetype, ReadStyle propertiesStyle)
   at TagLib.File.Create(String path, ReadStyle propertiesStyle)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, Windows Store applications are only able to access certain files, I seriously doubt the library your trying to use even supports the WinRT .NET Profile.

Comment: yes, but the basic application CAN access and play the same file, but the dll can't.

Comment: couldn't do it this way. used  MusicProperties instead, but thats not as good. :=

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the dll, if you have the source, I would fix HOW the file is accessed.  Actually I would just relocate the file in a location I could access it in.

Comment: yes, I tough of it , but I need to do this for 100 files. It would take a while while it load.

Comment: my final solution was to use a built in file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync(); then get album art through last.fm api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't do it this way. used MusicProperties instead, and then used lastfm api to get the needed info.. shame its so difficult in Win8 c# what is easy in normal C#

Answer (score 3):

You can use TagLibSharp to load tags by creating a StreamFileAbstraction and passing that to File.Create. This won't use any banned APIs.

```
public void ExampleCall(StorageFile storageFile)
{
    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType f = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    var file = File.Create(new StreamFileAbstraction(storageFile.Name, f.AsStream()));
}

public class StreamFileAbstraction : File.IFileAbstraction
{
    public StreamFileAbstraction(string name, Stream stream)
    {
        Name = name;
        ReadStream = stream;
        WriteStream = stream;
    }

    public void CloseStream(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Flush();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Stream ReadStream { get; private set; }
    public Stream WriteStream { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks. It's a late answer, so I won't try it, but I believe you. ;)

Comment: No problem, just figured I'd pop it in here for anyone else that stumbles across it like I did. Been stewing on it for a few weeks and MusicProperties finally tipped me over the edge yesterday.

Comment: @JamiePenney how did you get it through certification?
I did something similiar but it failed certification (with the certification kit) because of a ton of unsupported APIs.

Comment: But the reason for that might be that I'm not reading the tags but writing the album art.

Comment: @Stefan I didn't ever get around to submitting it - it was only ever running on my machine. It might have failed because TagLibSharp would have used a bunch of unsupported APIs in its DLL, even though we never touched them.

Answer (score 0):

For WinRT you need next:

```
var task = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
var stream = await task.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
 using (var info = File.Create(new StreamFileAbstraction(Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath), stream, stream)))
 {
      Album = info.Tag.Album;
      Comment = info.Tag.Comment;
      // more properties
 }
```

and you need add NuGet Packages - TagLib# Portable