# How can I set album art for a song in a Windows App (e.g. without tag-lib#)?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, taglib

I had thought that my Windows App was finished and ready for release.  However, during the certification process, ACK told me Tag-Lib# uses API that the Windows Store does not support.  Now I need to find some other way that the Windows Store DOES support to be able to programmatically set the album art for songs.  Any ideas?  (I would also be happy if anyone knew of a way to modify Tag-Lib# to comply with the Windows Store restrictions.)

Comment: I'm *very* curious how you got this to build in the first place.  Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14095651/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I just used the TagLab# NuGet package and it builds and runs fine

Comment: Wow, I see it.  This having been built with Mono and targeting .NET 2.0 somehow turns the IDE catatonic.  The rewrite you'll need is pretty painful, not in the least because it has a dependency on SharpZipLib which also contains forbidden fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Windows App Certification Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj572486) to see which API's are called. Then try to modify the Tag-Lib# source to not use those API's, or pick the relevant code and build your own library.

Though I think, given it's used for reading and writing files, it relies on `System.IO` which will require quite some rewriting to `Windows.Storage`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, TagLib# comes already compiled and thus cannot be modified (easily).  I may be wrong on this though.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I also tried that.  However, I believe that Hans Passant's comment pretty much sums up my experience.